# Open website with selenium as an Android device

Tags: c#, android, selenium

I want to make a program with opens a website "in mobile view", I don't really know how to call it, but I want that the website thinks I'm using an android phone.

I have tried it using ChromeOptions and changing the user-agent, but somehow it doesn't work.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.1.0; Phone) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.90 Mobile Safari/537.36");

driver = new ChromeDriver("./", options);
```

Answer (score 0):

This [site](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/mobile-emulation) has detailed documentation of using Mobile Emulation.

Moreover, after ChromeDriver v[2.11](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.11/notes.txt) has mobileEmulation  option.
For C#
Use something like this,

```
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

        chromeOptions.EnableMobileEmulation("Pixel 2");
        chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("safebrowsing.enabled", true);
        chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("credentials_enable_service", false);
        chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);

        ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\chromedriver");

        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service, chromeOptions);
```

You can enter the device required like iPhone X, iPad Pro, Samsung s7, etc..

Also remember that,
EnableMobileEmulation("deviceName");

**deviceName:**
             The name of the device to emulate. The device name must be a valid device name
             from the Chrome DevTools Emulation panel.
**Note:** specifying an invalid device name will not throw an exception, but will generate
             an error in Chrome when the driver starts. To unset mobile emulation, call this
             method with null as the argument.